# CMake Trouble including directories

Tags: android, cmake

Hi I'm having some trouble getting different libraries to recognize eachother when they are in different directories.

Here's an image of my project structure:

[image: Structure]

For example, I have a library called `peac` and at the top of`eig33sym.hpp` there is the following include to `Eigen`

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

Just to clarify, if I change these includes to something like this instead, then it runs fine.

```
#include "../Eigen/Core"
#include "../Eigen/Dense"
```

However since I have a few different libraries that all reference each other it's not really ideal to go through and change every file.

That being said, I saw somewhere that maybe what I want to do is use `include_directories()` inside my `CMakeLists.txt` to solve this issue but so far I haven't had any luck.

Here's what I currently have in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
include_directories(D:/opencv-3.4.9-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

include_directories(D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/Eigen/)

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(native-lib lib_opencv ${log-lib})
```

Regardless fo what I try I always seem to get the same error

```
..\..\..\..\src\main\cpp\include\peac\eig33sym.hpp:37:11: fatal error: 'Eigen/Core' file not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: An include directory **plus** a string given to `#include` should give the **absolute path** to the header file. In your case this sum is `D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/Eigen/` + `Eigen/Core` gives `D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/Eigen/Eigen/Core`. With double `Eigen` component this path is wrong, isn't it? Correct path - `D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/Eigen/Core` - is achieved by sum `D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/` + `Eigen/Core`. This uses `D:/AndroidFreightMeasure/app/src/main/cpp/include/` as include directory.

Comment: You *should* be able to include the header files with `#include <Eigen/Dense>` by verifying your include paths as suggested. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes this was the issue, thank you